# insert 100000+ Record in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to **insert record** on mySql Database table....i have **80k** record on **CSV** file.so, i created a insert into query. when i am trying to fire query on **browser(localhost/myphpadmin)**
it's show me "**FATAL**" error for the **Time Out**....so, how can i insert whole data on table?

When I Immport Text File

**Error:**

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

Comment: This question is either `Too Localized` or `Not a Real Question`. Please check the FAQ for help on asking good questions. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure about the actual syntax, but I know in phpMyAdmin you need to use the `LOAD DATA` option for importing big spreadsheets.

Comment: ya know about that but same problem with that

Answer (score 2):

since you are running it on localhost .. why don't you run the whole sql file in the mysql db itself using the following syntax

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p -h localhost YOUR-DATA-BASE-NAME-HERE < YOUR-.SQL.FILE-NAME-HERE
```

Also for executing large queries in phpmyadmin you can visit this previous post..
[how to import a very large query over phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427297/how-to-import-a-very-large-query-over-phpmyadmin)

Comment: plz ans my Question after My Edit !!!

Comment: @DJ I have added more content and might prove helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Insert into table values (row1 values),(row 2 values),  .... Err etc

Comment: it will work for the 1k or 2k but not for the 80k records.