# How to create a MySQL database from dump file in expect/TCL script?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, tcl, expect

I just wanted to execute this bash command in expect script:

```
mysql -u root -h localhost -proot dbTest < temp.sql
```

I added `spawn` to the beginning but it is not working. I think "<" symbol means nothing in expect!

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found a solution for this problem. I avoided the "<" symbol, so we can use this command instead:

```
spawn mysql -u root -h localhost -proot dbTest -Bse "source temp.sql"
```

Answer (score 2):

`spawn` does not support the `<` direction but you can do like this:

```
spawn sh -c "mysql -u root -h localhost -proot dbTest < temp.sql"
```

Seems like you want to run `mysql` in the non-interactive way so you can also use `Expect`'s `system` command:

```
system "mysql -u root -h localhost -proot dbTest < temp.sql"
```

or `Tcl`'s `exec` command:

```
exec mysql -u root -h localhost -proot dbTest < temp.sql >@ stdout 2>@ stderr
```

You may need to put the whole `system` or `exec` command in a `catch` block in case the `mysql` fails:

```
catch {system "mysql ..."} catched
# or
catch {exec mysql ...} catched
```

Comment: Yes, it works well, that really a good option. In addition, it will help me in the future as well.

Answer (score 1):

People tend to use sqldump and mysqldump. I like the quote in the below link saying `rubbish` with phpmyadmin:

[how to import a very large query over phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427297/how-to-import-a-very-large-query-over-phpmyadmin)

Concerning `cron` or `expect` ...

I know cron has trouble say with dates and often what works at a command line has to be shoved in a bash script for easier work. Then cron runs the .sh script versus embedded string.

Also it is a duplicate question of yours from 2 hours ago.

Comment: Thank you so much again, yes I wrote it again in better way. well, you are right, I can make a .sh file with command and call it from expect. It is actually long way but I will try it.

Comment: Look into tcl braces {} maybe around the `<` sign I don't know. Good luck

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working. However, I got two more correct answers to this question. thanx again