# Expect: Bash Scripting with Expect and Postgresql

Tags: bash, postgresql, expect

**Necessary Info:**
I'm trying to use *expect* to automate a password involving a command with *PostgreSQL* in a *BASH* script. I've tried mimicking several examples I found here on *StackOverflow.com* and also other resources on the internet with no success.

**Issue:** I'm still getting prompted for input.

**Code:**

*Extra Info: password is a global variable not shown in this snippet*

```
database_work(){
sudo -u postgres createdb tinyows
sudo python /$1/database.py

expect <<- DONE
spawn sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -d tinyows < `pg_config   --sharedir`/contrib/postgis-2.1/postgis.sql 
        expect "*?assword:*"
        send -- "$password\r"
        send -- "\r"
        expect eof
DONE
expect <<- DONE
spawn sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -d tinyows < `pg_config   --sharedir`/contrib/postgis-2.1/spatial_ref_sys.sql 
        expect "*?assword:*"
        send -- "$password\r"
        send -- "\r"
        expect eof
DONE
}
```

**Ending Note:** I appreciate any help and advice anyone gives, thank you.

Comment: Turn on debugging and expect will show you why it's not matching: `expect -d <<-DONE`

Comment: `spawn` does not support the `<` direction. See [my answer for another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31236758/900078).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to solve your carpentry problem with a welder.

This won't work for a number of reasons.

`sudo` intentionally prevents you from redirecting its stdin, instead reading it from the terminal. This is partly to make password stealing wrappers harder, but is mostly useful so that things like `some-command | sudo othercommand` work even if `sudo` has to prompt for a password. To disable this you must pass the `--stdin` flag to `sudo`, explicitly telling it you want it to read a password from stdin.

`sudo` may or may not actually prompt for a password at each invocation, depending on its settings, whether the user ran it recently, etc. `expect` won't like that.

The better way to do this is to set up `sudo` so that you don't have to supply a password to perform the desired action, or get the user to run your whole script under `sudo` first so they can interactively respond to the prompt. Then use a regular shell script, or preferably an automation tooling framework like Ansible or Puppet.

BTW, on anything except ancient PostgreSQL releases you should be using `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` not running a loader script through `psql`.

Comment: nice info - but the upvote is for "doing carpentry with a welder"